# ggplot2: remove gap introduced by geom_area?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create very simple plot - essentially a line graph but with the area coloured under the line to  designate AM and PM (I produce several of these in a faceted grid as I want the reader to quickly see the different between AM and PM values) .

My difficulty is that the use of **geom_area** introduces a break where the ampm values change from *AM* to *PM*.

If you remove geom_area, the plot is correctly represented by the continuous geom_line.

If you add a geom_area the break reoccurs.

I haven't found a solution to this online. Would anyone know how to remove this break?

[example of gap added using geom_area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQ6tO.png)

```
# sample data
clicks <- c(513, 400, 200, 101,45, 60,89, 222, 385, 628, 1004, 987, 1020,970, 753, 645, 580, 723, 823, 765, 894, 710, 623, 500)

day <- rep("Monday", 24)
hour <- seq(0,23)
am <- rep("AM", 12)
pm <- rep("PM", 12)
ampm <- append(am,pm )

df_click_data.monday <-data.frame(day, hour, ampm,  clicks)
df_click_data.monday$ampm <-factor(df_click_data.monday$ampm, levels=c("AM","PM"))

# simple plot to illustrate problem
p <- ggplot(df_click_data.monday, aes(x = hour, y=clicks )) +
   geom_line(size=0.4) +
   geom_area(aes(fill=ampm))
p
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a workaround that adds an artificial point to correctly fill the 'AM' area:

```
new.lines <- df_click_data.monday[df_click_data.monday$hour==12,]
new.lines$ampm <- "AM"
new.lines$hour <- 11.9999
df_click_data.monday <- rbind(df_click_data.monday, new.lines)

p <- ggplot(df_click_data.monday, aes(x = hour, y=clicks )) +
  geom_line(size=0.4) +
  geom_area(aes(fill=ampm))
p
```

[image]

Alternatively, you may want to use `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`:

```
ggplot(data = df_click_data.monday, aes(x = hour, y = clicks, fill = ampm)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

```
ggplot(data = df_click_data.monday, aes(x = hour, y = clicks, fill = ampm)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width=1)
```

[image]

Comment: adding an artificial point  is certainly a pragmatic solution. I'll make a copy of the data set to make a distinction between the original data and the 'plotting' data with the additional point. The other two approaches are useful too. Thank you @DJack